# Issue with SUMPRODUCT formula with date and text

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I m using the below formula to get the red point but i m receiving an error `#VALUE`. i also use `*` instead of `,` but i get the same error

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$M$1=P1),($A$2:$A$30=P2),($B$2:$M$30))`

[image]

Any help will appreciate.

Comment: The multiplier is definitely the right way to go. Furthermore, you give `SUMPRODUCT` a matrix to add values from but those values are text > `Jan`.

Comment: i used `VLOOKUP` and i get there. thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1):

You have text columns within that data, so you can't multiply. You actually want INDEX and MATCH:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$M$30,MATCH(P2,$A$2:$A$30,0),MATCH(P1,$B$1:$M$1,0))
```

Comment: Not behind a pc to check but you might want to adjust the column match to search from b1, or change the index matrix to start from column a. Was thinking of this, but expected op to have multiple lines to add and therefore using Sumproduct. If it's just the one line with text then you absolutely right.

Comment: @JvdV Good spot on the column match, thanks. For the other, the result is a text value, so I can't see how summing could apply.

Comment: Me neither, hence my comment under the question. The problem is textual values. If those were numbers, and there are multiple lines that meet the criteria (unclear to me if that could be the case), then Sumproduct is the way to go.